# How to see or show IN LIVE the samples of google api client for python?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

From the [Google Code Site](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/SampleApps) I downloaded the file "google-api-python-client.zip" with the python samples for google app engine, this ZIP file contains the next samples:

adexchangebuyer
adexchangeseller
adsense
adsensehost
analytics
api-python-client-doc
appengine
audit
blogger
coordinate
customsearch
dfareporting
django_sample
groupssettings
lista
maps_engine
plus
prediction
searchforshopping
service_account
storage
storage_serviceaccount_appengine
tasks_appengine
translate
urlshortener
youtube

I'm interested in the "django_sample" sample, however I like review all samples. The zip file downloaded has one setup file but I cannot run it.

Comment: it's not clear what you want. Can you make your question more specific? What was the problem that you ran into? Did you get an error? What did it say? Was there a specific step that you had trouble with? What was it?

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminGolder: I dont know how to run the examples.

Comment: @BenjaminGolder I need see the samples in execution, in live!, Thansk for your help.